# Is farcically an acceptable replacement for ludicrously?

Tags: meaning

Someone in another one of my questions said that it is not; however, I must ask, "Is *farcically* an acceptable replacement for *ludicrously*?" Based on the definition of *farce*, I can partially understand why it would not be. One of the definitions of *farcical* also adds to this. However, synonyms for *farcical* include: `absurd, ridiculous, preposterous` and `ludicrous.` If these are synonyms, why then would *farcically* not be an acceptable replacement for *ludicrously*? In addition, under some of the definitions of *farcical*, it is indeed defined as *ludicrous* or *absurd*. If this is, why then would *farcically* not be an acceptable replacement for *ludicrously*?

Comment: Because of strong associations with the theatrical genre, ***farce*** (and derivatives) often carry more overtones of *deliberately* absurd behaviour, *intended* to cause amusement. Thus, if you're the kind of person who laughs at the sight of a tortoise stuck on it's back, you might describe the poor animal's attempts to right itself as ***ludicrous***, but probably not ***farcical***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say they're not replacements.

[farcical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/farcical#farcical__2)

> Relating to or resembling farce, especially because of absurd or ridiculous aspects:

[ludicrous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ludicrous)

> So foolish, unreasonable, or out of place as to be amusing:
>
> *it’s ludicrous that I have been fined*

But not: *it’s farcical that I have been fined*

Also, as @FumbleFingers said, farcical things are often intentionally funny. `Ludicrous` carries no such connotation. If anything, it connotes the opposite.

[Oxford]

---

*"If these are synonyms, why then would farcically not be an acceptable replacement for ludicrously?"*

I hope you realize that most synonyms aren't exact replacements of each other. They are closely related, but they usually have a specific difference in meaning, which is probably why they exist as separate words.

Comment: I understand that words aren't exact replacements for one another simply because they're synonyms. There are, however, many dictionary websites that you can find my simply searching "farcical", and they give you the definition: `resembling farce; ludicrous; absurd.` Also, *Merriam-Webster.com* gives a very misleading example sentence: `the farcical routine that a person has to go through to get a refund from that company.` That sentence, in no way, gives the incite that *farcical* has an *often intentionally funny* denotation.

Comment: @ClaytonGeist: No it doesn't, but it's farcical in that it resembles a farce. In this context, farcical is apt and more specific than `ludicrous`. You can think of farcical as a subset of ludicrous: it can replace ludicrous in some (very specific) cases but not all of them.

Comment: OK, I think I understand a bit better. Thank you. It would make sense that it would act as a subset of ludicrous.